# PhpStorm > Settings > Vue Template Style Space not being inserted in moustache curly braces on typing

Tags: vue.js, phpstorm

PhpStorm (on Mac) v 2022.3.3

I would like for spaces to be inserted (as soon as I type them) after the opening double braces and closing double braces in my Vue template file. EventCard.vue:

What is currently happening:
[image: currently]

What I would like to happen, cursor placed here:
[image: desired]

From docs: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2022.3/vue-js.html#ws_vue_spaces

[image]

I have not changed any of the settings mentioned above.

Settings (for both project & IDE) shown seem correct:
[image]

I know it's small but it's highly annoying that this is not working!

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: The spaces should be added on code reformatting. Are they?

Comment: yes on select code > reformat file, it inserts the spaces. So not sure why it doesn't do it when I type?